# How do I use user input, obtained through a function, to alter global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables, mud

I have a global variable that needs to be altered by user input generated by a function.

I'm trying to make a **Zork style text game** and want the character name, `input` by the user during a character creation `function`, to **alter a global variable**.

I've been able to create a `class` to store character information and been able to display most of the information in the `class` on a mock command prompt I have appear when `input` options are available to the user.

I use a `global variable` to define the character's name until the character creation stage.  I use the '`global`' keyword in the `creation()` `function` to alter the 'name' `variable` with user `input`.

When the prompt is ready to be used it still only displays the **name as `00`** instead of the `input` generated during the `creation()` `function`

I am exceedingly novice.  Any advice, tips or direction would be cherished.

```py
import time
name = "00" ##this is what we want to change

##
def Intro():
    print("\n\n\nWelcome to the game.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("This is an attempt to make an interactive text based game.")

##
def Creation():
    Character_name = input("\nWhat will your Character's name be: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nWelcome to the game " + Character_name + " \n" )
    time.sleep(1.5)
    Character_class = input("In one word, name " + Character_name + "'s profession: ")
    t00n = Character_name + " the " + Character_class
    global name ##here I am using the global keyword
    name = t00n
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n" + t00n + "\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    next_func = input("When ready type 'next' to begin.\n>>>:")

    if next_func == "next":
        segway()
    else:
        Jump()

##
def Jump():
    Jump_Prompt = input("Just 'Jump' on in\n>>>: ")
    if Jump_Prompt == "Jump":
        segway1()
    else:
        Jump()

##
def segway():
    print("A room with options to choose from")
    prompt()    

class Character:

    def __init__(self, name, HP, full_HP, AtS, AR):
        self.name = name ##should = t00n now?
        self.hp = HP
        self.full_HP = full_HP
        self.AtS = AtS
        self.AR = AR

    def stat_bar(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format("[Name:]", self.name, "[HP:]", self.hp, "[Max HP:]", self.full_HP)

Player1 = Character(name, 100, 100, 1, 0)

##
def prompt():
    _pr = input("<<< " + Character.stat_bar(Player1) + " >>> \n")
    return _pr


#Begin
Intro()
Creation()
segway()

##The prompt() function still displays the name as 00 even tho the creation() function is using the 'global' keyword to change the 'name' variable to the user input.
```

Comment: so in the prompt when someone types his name, in next prompt it should come up e,g `<<< [Name:] Joe [HP:] 100 [Max HP:] 100 >>> ` if Joe was the name typed?

Comment: Essentially yes.  I'd like it to return the `t00n variable` defined in `creation()`  The user inputs two pieces of data that that can be returned using the `t00n variable`.  I'd like to change the `global name` `variable` to call the `t00n variable` in `creation()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the global keyword in your `prompt`, and update `Player1.name` with that global name

```
def prompt():

    #Take name from global scope
    global name

    #Assign it to Player1 name
    Player1.name = name

    _pr = input("<<< " + Character.stat_bar(Player1) + " >>> \n")
    return _pr
```

Then your prompt will work as intended, for example

```
Welcome to the game.
This is an attempt to make an interactive text based game.

What will your Character's name be: Joe

Welcome to the game Joe 

In one word, name Joe's profession: Don

Joe the Don

When ready type 'next' to begin.
>>>:next
A room with options to choose from
<<< [Name:] Joe the Don [HP:] 100 [Max HP:] 100 >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, took a little bit, but I think I found the problem.

You initialize Player 1 using the name variable before calling `Creation()`, where you change the global name variable, so Player1 is created with the original name “00.”

Move the line:

`Player1 = Character(name, 100, 100, 1, 0)`

Put it after `Creation()` at the bottom but before `segway()`

Python more or less executes any unindented code (code that isn’t in a function, class, etc.) from top to bottom.

So, moving from top to bottom in your program, it sets name to “00”, then creates Player1 with the original name, then calls `Intro()`, `Creation()` (which changes the name to t00n), and finally `segway()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If i move the `Player1 = Character(name, 100, 100, 1, 0)` then I get a **NameError: name 'Player1' is not defined.**

Comment: Can I see what your code looks like after you’ve moved it?

Comment: I don't know how to show you...  It won't let me fit all of it in the comment box.

Comment: class Character:

 def __init__(self, name, HP, full_HP, AtS, AR):
  self.name = name
  self.hp = HP
  self.full_HP = full_HP
  self.AtS = AtS
  self.AR = AR
 
 def stat_bar(self):
  return '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format("[Name:]", self.name, "[HP:]", self.hp, "[Max HP:]", self.full_HP)



##
def prompt():
 _pr = input("<<< " + Character.stat_bar(Player1) + " >>> \n")
 return _pr


#Begin
Intro()
Creation()
Player1 = Character(name, 100, 100, 1, 0)
segway()

Comment: See what happens if you put `global Player1` inside the stat_bar function